# Android: check wifi password validity without connecting to pre-configured network

Tags: android, passwords, wifi

I'm looking for a method to check password validity for a pre-configured wifi network without activating it. Any solution?

My Case:

1. Android is connected to a external device that works as a Wifi Acces Point
2. I need to configure this external device with one of my pre-configured wifi network
3. I ask the user for the pre-configured password (using a dialog)
4. I pass it to the external device

So, I want to check the password validity before passing it to the external device.

WifiConfiguration returns "*" as password so I can't compare directly the password provided by user with the current pre-configured password.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no 'elegant' way.

If you set password taken from a dialog to: `wifiConfig.preSharedKey` and than use method: `wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfig)` the configuration of given SSID is not added but gets overwriten. Than you call `wifiManager.reconnect()` to check if you can connect to your network (using `BroadcastReceiver` with filter `WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION`).

Now, if the password is correct you're good. But if it's not, you will be disconnected and asked by your Android device to provide correct password to be able to connect to network for which you changed the configuration.